# Inconsistent data with ReadProcessMemory C++

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

Here is the scoop, I have created a program that sleeps for 30 seconds..Nothing more. Within immunity debugger it looks as such:

```
0x00061000 >/$ 68 30750000    PUSH 7530; /Timeout = 30000. ms
```

The code for this program is :

```
#include <windows.h>
void main()
{
    Sleep(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read this line with a C++ program. This is the code for that process:

```
const char *procName = "blank.exe";
HANDLE hProc = GetProcHandle(procName);
if (hProc == NULL){
    cout << "Error Proccess Handle == NULL!!! Can not continue...";
    getch();
    return 1;
}
//Handle aquired continue.... //

cout << "Handle has been Aquired!\n";
LPVOID RMEM[100];
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)(0x00061000), &RMEM, sizeof(RMEM), 0);
cout << "Read Memory:" << RMEM;

getch();
return 0;
```

The problem is every time I run the program I get different results. example 3 results for three runs(00FBFC3C, 0086F9C4, 007CF5EO). I want to be able to read the value of sleep and then after this is perfected I want to overwrite it with a new value like: PUSH EA60; What is going on? I have read the msdn page I have tried looking at the values ReadProMem gives me and there is no such offset in the main module. I'm at a complete loss 0.o 
Any help and tips would be amazing.

Comment: Not sure about whomever else downvoted, but mine will be for failing to check the return code of `ReadProcessMemory`, even though it may not be failing (if you've checked it and shortened your code for readability, it's worth noting).  Separately, you might want to see if [Address Space Randomisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is in play - which depends on your compiler settings and version as well as OS version....

Comment: Why have you not supplied the code of the test program? Since the question relies upon that, its exclusion seems foolhardy.

Comment: I will edit the code. And Tony D It is reading memory, From what I do not know.   -- Please Note I'm rather new to this!
I thought that by pointing out that all the blank exe did was Sleep(30000) it was supplied already...

Comment: Downvote me if you must, but I'm going to apologize for the sometimes less-than-friendly community here. They're helpful, but manners and kindness can sometimes be fleeting.

Comment: `GetProcHandle` doesn't seem to be a Windows API function, and `LPVOID RMEM[100];` declares an array of 100 void pointers.

Comment: GetProcHandle Just gets the pid of a file and opens it with all access. How should I set up the buffer to hold the read data?

Comment: Ok, I added getlasterror And the last error is 299? I feel like a fool. I read msdn and they said on error it reutrns a non-zero digit so I just assumed.

Comment: Don't check for errors by adding calls to GetLastError. Check for errors by checking the return value. Only if that indicates failure do you then call GetLastError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine here, using win7 pro and 32 bit compiled programs. Both programs were built with Mingw and Code::Blocks, the target memory address was determined with the use of OllyDbg.

I can confirm that the delay is successfully changed. That's the purpose of the getchar() - it's to ensure the delay hasn't been started yet when we alter the target program's memory.

**1**. Target program source - main.c (hackMe.exe)

```
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
    getchar();
    Sleep(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

**2**. Target area of target program (using ollydbg)

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00401334  /$  8D4C24 04     LEA ECX,[ARG.1]
00401338  |.  83E4 F0       AND ESP,FFFFFFF0                         ; DQWORD (16.-byte) stack alignment
0040133B  |.  FF71 FC       PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[ECX-4]
0040133E  |.  55            PUSH EBP
0040133F  |.  89E5          MOV EBP,ESP
00401341  |.  51            PUSH ECX
00401342  |.  83EC 14       SUB ESP,14
00401345  |.  E8 D6050000   CALL 00401920
0040134A  |.  E8 41080000   CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.getchar>               ; [MSVCRT.getchar
0040134F  |.  C70424 307500 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.7],7530          ; /Time => 30000. ms
00401356  |.  E8 8D080000   CALL <JMP.&KERNEL32.Sleep>               ; \KERNEL32.Sleep
0040135B  |.  83EC 04       SUB ESP,4
0040135E  |.  90            NOP
0040135F  |.  8B4D FC       MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.2]
00401362  |.  C9            LEAVE
00401363  |.  8D61 FC       LEA ESP,[ECX-4]
00401366  \.  C3            RETN
```

**3.** Controlling program - main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
unsigned long GetProcessId( char* szProcName )
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    HANDLE hHandle;

    hHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    if( !Process32First( hHandle, &pe32 ) )
        return 0;

    while( Process32Next( hHandle, &pe32 ) )
    {
        if( stricmp( szProcName, pe32.szExeFile ) == 0 )
        {
            CloseHandle( hHandle );
            return pe32.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle( hHandle );
    return 0;
}

// reads a chunk of memory from a running program's memory space
// Buffer must already be allocaed and hold space for length bytes
BOOL readMemBlock(char *szProgName, unsigned long dwMemAddr, unsigned long length, void *Buffer)
{
    HANDLE hHandle;
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    BOOL resCode;
    DWORD lastErrCode;

    printf("%s, 0x%x, %d\n", szProgName, dwMemAddr, length);

    hHandle = OpenProcess( STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED|PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, GetProcessId( szProgName ) );

    if( hHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hHandle == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error opening process\n");
        if (!hHandle)
            printf("hHandle == NULL\n");
        else
            printf("INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
        return FALSE;
    }
    resCode = ReadProcessMemory( hHandle, (unsigned long*)dwMemAddr, Buffer, length, NULL );
    CloseHandle(hHandle);
    return resCode;
}

// reads a chunk of memory from a running program's memory space
// Buffer must already be allocaed and hold space for length bytes
BOOL writeMemBlock(char *szProgName, unsigned long dwMemAddr, unsigned long length, void *Buffer)
{
    HANDLE hHandle;
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    BOOL resCode;

    hHandle = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, GetProcessId( szProgName ) );
    if( hHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hHandle == NULL )
        return FALSE;

    resCode = WriteProcessMemory( hHandle, (unsigned long*)dwMemAddr, Buffer, length, NULL );
    CloseHandle(hHandle);
    return resCode;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long pId = GetProcessId("hackMe.exe");
    if (!pId)
    {
        printf("Proc handle NOT FOUND\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Proc handle aquired\n");
    unsigned char buffer[50];
    readMemBlock("hackMe.exe", 0x401334, 50, buffer); //unsigned long length, void *Buffer)
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        unsigned int curElem = buffer[i];
        printf("%02X ", (unsigned int)curElem);
        if ((i+1)%16 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    /* output
        Proc handle aquired
        hackMe.exe, 0x401334, 50
        8D 4C 24 04 83 E4 F0 FF 71 FC 55 89 E5 51 83 EC
        14 E8 D6 05 00 00 E8 41 08 00 00 C7 04 24 30 75  <-- want these 2 bytes 0x30, 0x75
        00 00 E8 8D 08 00 00 83 EC 04 90 8B 4D FC C9 8D
        61 FC
    */

    // change delay to 2.5 seconds (originally 30 secs)
    short newDelayValue = 2500;
    writeMemBlock("hackMe.exe", 0x401352, 2, &newDelayValue);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you just write that?

Comment: The `main` I wrote for this question, the rest was copied and pasted from a decade-old project that played WinMine.exe (minesweeper) on XP.

Comment: I am going to download ming. I assume it has something to do with visual studio 2013...

Comment: Anyhow Thank you for your Time. I'm going to have to examine this code and try to learn something from it.

Comment: Nope, nothing at all to do with VS. Your code will fail in the same way when compiled by all compilers. The code in this question commits the same sin as yours does by failing to check for errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - guilty as charged. ++ for the reminder that production quality code doesn't just belong in the workplace.

Comment: The problem was indeed, I wasn't reading the correct address. I looked at the code about and figured it out. Thank you guys, lesson learned...I will Start to use error checking more often instead of assuming things are working! Thank all very much!

Comment: @404 the problem was that you weren't checking for errors. The code here doesn't check for errors.

Comment: I have it working now, Took me awhile to figure out how it all worked but it did. Im currently trying to play with arithmetic and reversing the code for the stack lol. Still very new to me but I'm getting there day by day. You guys are helping a lot. I have all so begun to use error checks with every statement that may fail :)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the call to [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) is failing. Since you don't check for errors you've no way of knowing that. The documentation says:

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is 0 (zero). To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Your error checking might look like this:

```
if (!ReadProcessMemory(...))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    // report error, bail out, etc. 
}
```

My guess is that `ReadProcessMemory` fails because the address you pass is not valid in the target process. And then when you output `RMEM` you are merely outputting uninitialized values.

The first step for you is to fix the error handling. Once you've done that you'll know which API call fails and why it fails. Then likely you'll just need to supply a valid address.

Comment: Looks like a little pascal slipped in there with the `:=` :)